# Why would this C++ container within a container fail to fill with new values using MPI_Recv?

Tags: c++, mpi

I've implemented a working MPI send/recv, but I want to better organize and improve performance, so I am adopting the use of std::vector and std::map and sending data in chunks rather than individually. Below is my working code and failing code.

```
// working method (Individual send/recv)



// ... here the struct fvm::F is turned into an MPI datatype STRUCT_FACE to be used ...


// main rank 0

map<int, vector<fvm::F>> faces_buf;

// ... here faces_buf is initialized and the inside vectors are properly resized using vector.resize() ...


// the collection loop in main rank 0 (collects all faces from compute ranks 1, 2, 3, ...)
for(auto& fb : faces_buf){
   int compute_rank = fb.first;
   int n = 0;
   for(auto& f : fb.second){
      MPI_Recv(&f, 1, STRUCT_FACE, compute_rank, (n++ + 100000), MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
   }
}

// print results of collection
for(auto& fb : faces_buf){
    for(auto& f : fb.second){
        cerr << "f.T " << f.T << endl;
        if(f.T == 0.){
            goto done;
        }
    }
}
done:;




// compute ranks 1, 2, 3, ...

vector<fvm::F> faces;

// ... here faces vector is filled with values ...

for(auto& f : faces){
   MPI_Send(&f, 1, STRUCT_FACE, 0, (f.id + 100000), MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}


// Works as intended!
```

.

.

```
// failing method (Chunk send/recv)


// ... here the struct fvm::F is turned into an MPI datatype STRUCT_FACE to be used ...


// main rank 0

map<int, vector<fvm::F>> faces_buf;

// ... here faces_buf is initialized and the inside vectors are properly resized using vector.resize() ...

// the collection loop in main rank 0 (collects all faces from compute ranks 1, 2, 3, ...)
for(auto& fb : faces_buf){
   int compute_rank = fb.first;
   MPI_Recv(fb.second.data(), fb.second.size(), STRUCT_FACE, compute_rank, (compute_rank + 100000), MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
}

// print results of collection
for(auto& fb : faces_buf){
    for(auto& f : fb.second){
        cerr << "f.T " << f.T << endl;
        if(f.T == 0.){
            goto done;
        }
    }
}
done:;



// compute ranks 1, 2, 3, ...

vector<fvm::F> faces;

// ... here faces vector is filled with values ...

MPI_Isend(faces.data(), faces.size(), STRUCT_FACE, 0, (rank + 100000), MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqf);
int flagf = 0;
while(true){
   MPI_Test(&reqf, &flagf, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
   if(flagf){
      break;
   }
}

// Fails to recv new fvm::F values
```

The output of the working method:

```
f.T 298.15
f.T 298.15
f.T 298.15
f.T 298.15
f.T 298.15
...
...
...
```

The output of the failing method:

```
f.T 298.15
f.T 298.15
f.T 298.15
f.T 8.48798e-315
f.T 0
```

Why would the second method fail, while the first succeeds?

Comment: Does using `MPI_Send` instead of `MPI_Isend` in the failing example still exhibit the problem?

Comment: @dast99 Yes, MPI_Send produces the same output in the failing method.

Comment: Have you validated the return codes of MPI_Send and MPI_Recv

Comment: start checking `MPI_Recv()` does receive the expected number of faces. Then please provide self-contained reproducers, the error might be in the code you did not show.

Comment: If I had to make a guess from current information I would guess that there is a size mismatch between the size of `fvm::F` and what MPI expects from the data type you created.

Comment: @dast99 The return codes for both are MPI_SUCCESS.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I just used MPI_Get_count and MPI_Status and it is receiving the expected count.

Comment: @dast99 I think that may be the case somehow, because the failed output also repeats itself.  Almost like the values are shifted in memory.  But I can't figure out why working method wouldn't have the same issue....

Comment: @alvrm You'd either read/write slightly short or past the end of the object. But on the next iteration the pointer (i.e `&f`) would be correct again because your loop in the first case uses the size of `fvm::F`. But in the chunked case they are all packed tightly together according to the size of `STRUCT_FACE`

Comment: maybe you forgot to resize some thing, but how would I know?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet sorry I don't have a stand alone code, I might show the full thing if I can't get my next adjustment to work

Comment: @dast99 I think you nailed.  Because I remember the fvm::F struct had incorrect attribute values even in the working methods (remembering form days ago).  It makes sense that the chunk send would show up as a repeating pattern.  Now I just need to double check the MPI_Datatype creation and struct....

Comment: @dast99 I had extra `int` values my fvm::F struct. It works now, and I'm pretty sure it fixed another problem I was having, so I appreciate the help

Comment: @alvrm Glad to be of help, do you want to create an answer and mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fvm::F had more attributes than MPI_Datatype STRUCT_FACE.